# How come (x*y)+(x*z')+(y*z) = (x*z')+(y*z)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

As the title says, I just can't figure this one out.

I started with the initial function: f(x,y,z) = (x'yz) + (xy'z') + (xyz') + (xyz) and I have simplified it all the way down to this:

f=(x*y)+(x*z')+(yz).

I found out that the solution was: f=(x*z')+(y*z)  but I can't see how the (xy) just disappears.

Comment: What is your x' notation?  x not?  Or complex conjugate of x?  And why does your title not match your text?

Comment: @TimWescott It’s not x. Note the Boolean-algebra tag.

Comment: That's pretty wild the way you duplicated terms to get your simplification. I've not seen that done before. Took me a while to figure out how you got what you did.

Comment: I think this question is not really EE. It belongs to math.SE.

Comment: @Ariser You think digital electronics is not EE?

Comment: @user110971: At which part of the question digital electronics are mentioned? I only read boolean algebra, nothing else.

Comment: @Ariser Boolean algebra is the foundation of digital electronics. It is applied mathematics, so it is used by both engineers and mathematicians. The same way asking what the Fourier transform of the rect function can be considered both an engineering and a mathematical problem. In fact, I’m willing to bet that more EEs are familiar with Boolean algebra than mathematicians.

Comment: @user110971 ok, I do not deny digital electronics rely on BA. But analog electronics are based (among other mathematical disciplines) on e.g. linear algebra. I bet a question on solving a matrix inversion w/o any relation to a circuit will be closed here as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about electrical design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

$$\bar{x}yz + x\bar{y}\bar{z} + xy\bar{z} + xyz = (x + \bar{x})yz + (y + \bar{y})x\bar{z} = yz + x\bar{z}.$$

Alternatively

$$xy + yz + x\bar{z} =  xy(z + \bar{z}) + yz + x\bar{z} = (1 + x)yz + (1 + y)x\bar{z} = yz + x\bar{z}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the final expression is a MUX:
$$yz + x\bar{z}$$

When `z` is 1, the output is `y`.

When `z` is 0, the output is `x`.

The contribution of OR'ing `xy` to the output of the MUX is redundant, because it is only 1 when both inputs to the MUX are 1, yet the MUX is already letting through one of the inputs (and we're saying both of them are `1` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 variables.  Make a truth table with 8 rows in it.  Fill the output in based on the formula. Transfer that to a 2x4 K-map and minimize the covers. I always found visual minimization easier than algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The X*Y result is a redundant output of the logic table, I did not scrub this one back to just 0 or 1 to make the point on this one. its showing 2 seperate OR statements are returning true for that input set.

Left most is with X*Y, second column is without,

When X and Y are both "1", the result of the function is always true, as if Z is "0" then its caught by the (X*Z'), if Z is "1", it is caught by the (Y*Z)

[image]